# Targeting netcoreapp in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

Dears, I don't see the option for targeting netcoreapp when I want to create a new project. I've already installed framework and sdk but I still don't see it in the list. Please check screenshot attached.

[image: net core option missed]
What should I do else to be able to target net core framework?

UPDATE:
Actually, I need to retarget Unit test project to netcoreapp1.1. How can I do this? I don't see netcoreapp option in the project properties "Target Framework" list.

[image]

Comment: Select `.NET Core` up that list?

Comment: Select .NET Core on left menu. *(Templates > Visual C# > .NET Core)*

Comment: Actually, I need to retarget Unit test project to netcoreapp1.1. How can I do this? I don't see netcoreapp option in the project properties "Target Framework" list.

Comment: I'm note sure you can do that.. 
I think the better solution is create a new one which the good targeting and migrate your code.

Comment: Well, once I create new unit test project it is targeted to .NET framework and when I try to change it via properties page I don't see the netcoreapp option. Like on the second screenshot.

Comment: Looks like the net-core does support the xunit projects from out of the box, so you just need to create that type of project.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be concerned by this option. Go to the template ".Net Core" and choose the template that you are interested for.

The target option will be define in the project.json (if your are using .net core 1.0 in project.json or .csproj if version >).

But, have a look on the official documentation to have a better picture of it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/